# Poker with infinite stack size

Tags: game-theory, infinite-games, nash-equilibrium

In two-player No Limit Texas Hold 'Em (NLHE), the optimal strategy depends on the "effective stack size," that is maximum amount of money held by one of the players (in the sequel I'll just assume both players start with the same amount of money).
As the effective stack size increases, the computational cost of solving the game increases, as the number of available game histories becomes larger. My question is whether we can say that the optimal strategy converges to something, and further whether the thing it converges to is also a Nash equilibrium for the *infinite* version where the stack size is infinite.

Unfortunately, there's some ambiguity in what would be meant by the infinite version of the game so I'll give some possible versions below. The game is complex enough that you should probably read the Wikipedia page if you aren't familiar with it, but I'll introduce notation for discussion purposes below.

### Finite game betting rules

1. There are 4 betting rounds. Round 1 proceeds as follows:

   - Players $P_1$ and $P_2$ each start with money $S_{0}$
   - The initial money in the pot is $m_1$
   - $P_1$ makes a mandatory bet of $b_{1,1} = 1$. $P_1$ loses \$1.
   - $P_2$ makes a mandatory bet of $b_{1, 2} = 2$. $P_2$ loses \$2.
   - Now, for an unlimited number of iterations, player $P_k$ on turn $n$ may:

     - Fold, so that $P_{-k}$ collects the $m_1 + P_{1, n-2}$. The game now ends.
     - Make a bet $b_{1, n} \ge b_{1, n - 1}$ and lose $b_{1, n} - b_{1, n - 2}$ dollars

       - If $b_{1, n} = b_{1, n - 1}$ (**call**), the betting round ends
       - If $b_{1, n} > b_{1, n-1}$ (**raise**), it must be the case that either:

         - $b_{1,n} - b_{1, n-2}$ is all of $P_k$'s remaining money
         - $b_{1,n} - b_{1, n - 2} \ge b_{1, n - 2}$, i.e. the bet is increased by at least the amount the last raise increased it
   - The round ends when a player calls or folds. If no one folded and the last bet was the $n$th bet, the pot is now $m_2 = m_1 + 2 b_{1, n}$
2. Subsequent rounds are identical to the first round with the difference that there are no mandatory bets, $P_2$ makes the first bet, and the initial minimum bet must have $b_{k, 1} \ge 1$.
3. Before round 1, 2 cards are dealt (hidden) to each player. Before rounds 2, 3, and 4, respectively 3, 1, and 1 cards are placed face up as public information.
4. After round 4, if no one has folded, the player with the best combination of 5 of the 7 cards they can see collects the value of the pot in winnings.

### Infinite versions

The problem with an infinite version of NLHE is that there may be a non-terminating sequence of raises. I believe the following are reasonable resolutions to consider:

- Game $A$: An infinite sequence of raises means neither player receives any money, so their net reward from the game is $-\infty$
- Game $B$: An infinite sequence of raises is a tie, so that both players receive $m_0 / 2$ total reward

### Questions

1. Can we say anything about Nash equilibria in either of these infinite games? It seems that Game $A$ should lead to strategies which lead to 0 probability mass to infinite sequences of raises, so I expect it to have some sort of well-defined equilibrium.
2. Can we say anything about the convergence of an optimal strategy for the finite game to the optimal strategy for the infinite game?

As the rules are quite complex, I'm interested in these questions both for the full game, and for any simplifications which might be more tractable.

Edit: Per a DM, here is one simplification which might be easier to analyze: One round of betting only, with the full board already dealt out. It seems like knowing how to handle this case is a subproblem of the larger question.

Comment: What is the utility function of the players when the stack size is infinite?

Comment: Just the number of dollars won or lost. I realize it doesn't make much sense to value additional dollars if one has an infinite stack, but that seems like just a practical problem.